# Поменять местами строки максимального и минимального значения произведения

Tags: c++

Написать функцию для нахождения  произведения элементов для каждой строки двумерного динамического массива. Поменять местами строки с максимальным и минимальным значением произведения. Если с первым справился, то со вторым затрудняюсь, не пойму как поменять их местами, вот что вышло. Буду благодарен если подскажите/подправите сам код, очень устал сидеть над этой задачей, заранее спасибо!

```
 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void sum(int** V,int n,int m);   
void main()
{ // создание матрицы n строк m столбцов
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus"); 
    int n,m;
    cout<<"Количество строк :?";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Количество столбцов :?";
    cin>>m;
    int** V=new int*[n]; // выделение памяти
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        V[i]=new int[m];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            
            V[i][j] = rand() % 10; // генерируем случайные числа они в массиве будут от 0до10. // для ввода чисел в ручную используем cin>>V[i][j];
            cout<<V[i][j]<<"\t"; // вывод массива
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
   sum(V,n,m); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // освобождение памяти массива
        delete[] V[i];
    delete[] V;
    system("pause");
    
}
 
void sum(int** V,int n,int m)
{
    int min,max;
        min=max=0;
    int max_i,min_i;
    max_i=min_i=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        int p=1;
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
             p*=V[i][j]; // подсчет произведения в каждой строке
        
        if(p>max)
            max=V[i][j];
            max_i=i;
            if(p<min)
                min=V[i][j];
            min_i=i;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int temp = V[i][min_i];
        V[i][min_i] = V[i][max_i];
        V[i][max_i] = temp;
        cout<<i+1<<" строка, произведения = " << p<< endl;
    }
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

двумерный мерный массив в c++ - это всего лишь одномерный массив указателей на еще один одномерный массив

поэтому чтобы поменять местами 2 строки достаточно поменять местами указатели на них

```
int** arr = new int* [height];

for (int index = 0; index < height; index ++)
    arr[index] = new int [width];

// переставляем местами i и j строки

int* tmp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = tmp;
```